# How to read a file that has extended ascii characters?

Tags: assembly, mips

To read the 'ú' for example, when I read that, he spent two bytes, with the number 195, and the other with the number 186. But in ascii table: http://www.asciitable.com/ this character is 163.

How could I read from a text file that has in the text, for example: 'ú' '║' '±' and I can play it for extended ascii?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: I wish I could give asciitable.com a downvote. There is no such character set as "Extended ASCII".

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII?

Comment: @m0skit0 `The use of the term is sometimes criticized,[1][2][3] because it can be mistakenly interpreted that the ASCII standard has been updated to include more than 128 characters or that the term unambiguously identifies a single encoding, both of which are untrue.` (Note; the fact that this nonsense term is "criticized" is supported by 3 references, and nothing else in the article is supported by any references! I think that makes my point...)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley `Criticized` is different from `existing`.

Comment: @m0skit0 The _term_ "extended ASCII" exists but _the character set_ does not. Bottom line is that **you can't read a file if you don't know which character set and encoding it is using.** You can read all files as CP437 since every byte value corresponds to one character. But, unless it's from a Western culture circa 1990, it's probably wrong.

Comment: @MMichaelRodrigues You seem to want to represent the characters with a different encoding in memory than as in the file. If so which [character set and encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings) do you want to convert to?

Comment: @TomBlodget i have than mount a alphabet with the characters, showing the each characters and the counting.

Comment: I suggest a jump table or a switch-like statement. It would have to be two, three or four levels deep for byte values that indicate continuation bytes in the UTF-8 encoding. Depending on your target character set, only two might be needed. Another way would be to convert UTF-8 to codepoint values (equiv to UTF-32) and then search a table or tree.